# Difference between aidl and intent

Tags: android, android-intent, aidl

Sorry for noob question, but could anyone explain me the difference between aidl and intent ?
Would like to know when to use aidl and when to use intent? Thank you.

I am trying to understand Android basics and can't find a real difference between both of them

Comment: You cannot compare a plane and an apple.